# Authentication Order with SSH

Tags: ssh, password, public-key

When I login via ssh with `-v` I see that ssh is authenticating the following way

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password,hostbased
```

I would like to change the order ...any idea how?

My bigger problem is that user with locked accounts, can still login via public-keys. 
I have found that I could add the user to a group "ssh-locked" add deny that group from sshing, but I am still wondering if there is a way to tell ssh'd: 
**Please check password before keys...**

Comment: I think you're approaching this the wrong way - keys are (usually) more secure than passwords.  If the account is locked, you need to tell the sshd daemon to not let the user login regardless of the authentication method.

Comment: Like I said, I found a solution, via DenyGroups. I am asking it for the sake of interest.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The ssh server decides which authentication options it allows, the ssh client can be configured to decide in which order to try them.

The ssh client uses the `PreferredAuthentications` option in the ssh config file to determine this.

From `man ssh_config` ([see it online here](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)):

```
PreferredAuthentications
             Specifies the order in which the client should try protocol 2 authentication methods.  This allows a client to prefer
             one method (e.g. keyboard-interactive) over another method (e.g. password).  The default is:

                   gssapi-with-mic,hostbased,publickey,
                   keyboard-interactive,password
```

I don't believe it's possible, without playing with the source, to tell the OpenSSH server to prefer a certain order - if you think about it, it doesn't quite make sense anyway.

Comment: If you are using Git Bash for Windows, save your ssh config to `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: The order can make sense if one method depends on a previous one. For example 2FA under keyboard-interactive might depend on the user having first provided a valid password.

Comment: Can you post a source for where you copy-pasted the PreferredAuthentications info above? I don't see it in `man ssh`, nor in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, nor in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Where did you get this info?

Comment: Found it! It was in `man ssh_config`. I submitted an edit for review to update your answer to contain this source. Please cite sources next time! Many thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Adding this:

```
PreferredAuthentications keyboard-interactive,password,publickey,hostbased,gssapi-with-mic
```

...to my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` helped me to solve this, and saved a lot of time too!

You can check if it works by using `ssh -v user@host` command to connect, where `-v` stands for "verbose".

Comment: Ensure that you're adding this to the correct file `ssh_config` and not `sshd_config`. The latter will cause your ssh to fail!

Comment: You can also modify .ssh/config. Not everyone is able to become root.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the other two answers already mentioning the `PreferredAuthentications` option, I'd like to add **you don't need to edit any file to set this setting if you don't want**. Rather, you can just **set it at the command-line for an individual call to `ssh`**, with the `-o` option, as follows:

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey,gssapi-with-mic,hostbased,keyboard-interactive,password user@hostname
```

## References:

1. To read more about the `PreferredAuthentications` option, see `man ssh_config` ([see it online here](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)). Also read about the `ssh` `-o` option in the `man ssh` manual pages ([online here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh)).

Answer (score 1):

For a truly locked account, you can usually play with its expiration date as well. The ways to do so depend on your host's OS, e.g. on Linux it would be `chage -d 0 someuser`.

See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343535/what-is-the-solaris-equivalent-of-chage-d :-)